# Why I can not use anguar/material elements?

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I want to use angular materials. I got error.

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Personal data
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Type your name and age
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="First name">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Age">
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                       (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Self aware panel
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Currently I am {{panelOpenState ? 'open' : 'closed'}}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>I'm visible because I am open</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>


<!-- Copyright 2019 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
```

I import all related components but nothing works

```
import {
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatBadgeModule,
  MatBottomSheetModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatDividerModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatSliderModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatStepperModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
  MatTreeModule,
} from '@angular/material';
```

The error I got :

> mat-expansion-panel-header' is not a known element: 1. If
>   'mat-expansion-panel-header' is an Angular component, then verify that
>   it is part of this module.

There is no document how to apply to use these elemenets.

Comment: you import those modules into your `@NgModule`. not your component.

Answer (score 4):

Never forget to import `MatExpansionModule` to your `*.module.ts` file from `@angular/material/expansion`,

and then, do add it to your `imports` array of `@NgModule` of `*.module.ts` file

After this, you won't face any error related to `MatExpansionModule`.

PS: Try to import only those modules which are required for the app.

Answer (score 3):

`Angular` works with `modules` and `components`. Everything that your components will use must be registered in the `Module`. All you need to do is add these material modules to you `AppModule` class like this:

```ts
@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatBadgeModule,
        MatBottomSheetModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatDividerModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatRippleModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatTreeModule,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

This documentation can help you further https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules

Answer (score 1):

Have you added references to your relevant NG module, e.g. app.module.ts

```
.
.
.
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';
.
.
.
@NgModule({
  imports: [  
    MatDialogModule,

  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

use import {CdkAccordionModule} from '@angular/cdk/accordion'
instead of mat-accordian it will work same as mat-accordian